# Why use spring.factories for Spring Boot auto-configuration instead of annotations?

Tags: spring-boot

The documentation states:

> Developing auto-configuration and using conditions
>
> If you work in a company that develops shared libraries, or if you work on an open-source or commercial library, you might want to develop your own auto-configuration. Auto-configuration classes can be bundled in external jars and still be picked-up by Spring Boot.

If I have annotations for everything else (even  @AutoConfigureAfter or @AutoConfigureBefore annotations),

Why maintain a properties file to point to a class with an annotation?

Comment: have a look at explanation here: [Understanding Spring Boot](https://geowarin.com/understanding-spring-boot)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because we are not going to scan the world to figure out what auto-configuration classes exist in your project. For one, an auto-configuration is just a regular `@Configuration` class.

The way a Spring component is found is via explicit declaration or component scan but we need to know the list of auto-configuration classes way before we actually start the context.

Comment: Can you please tell me which class will scan the spring.factories and do to instantiation?

Comment: `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector` and friends. Not that this is an internal component of Spring Boot you're not supposed to deal with.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Since 2.7.0, Spring Boot introduced a new annotation `@AutoConfiguration` for auto-configuration classes. It seems that it is possible to scan the world to find all auto-configuration classes without spring.factories or org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports, however Spring Boot still relies on the files. I think it is because: 1. for compatibility reason; 2. the cost of scanning is relatively high. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not really, no. We don't scan the world, period. It's not about the cost but rather about detecting outside of the scope provided by the user. With a very large project, I can imagine this to be a bit costly though. It's still an opt-in mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

When SpringBoot app is starting, it will not scan all the classes in jars, So SpringBoot starter should specify which classes are auto-configured. For example, in spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE, it initializes like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //1. method run will call the construtor below
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

    public SpringApplication(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Class<?>... primarySources) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
        Assert.notNull(primarySources, "PrimarySources must not be null");
        this.primarySources = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(primarySources));
        this.webApplicationType = deduceWebApplicationType();
        //2. find all the classes whose key is ApplicationContextInitializer in spring.factories and initialize them 
        setInitializers((Collection) getSpringFactoriesInstances(
                ApplicationContextInitializer.class));
        setListeners((Collection) getSpringFactoriesInstances(ApplicationListener.class));
        this.mainApplicationClass = deduceMainApplicationClass();
    }

...
    private <T> Collection<T> getSpringFactoriesInstances(Class<T> type,
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object... args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        // Use names and ensure unique to protect against duplicates
        Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<>(
                //3. use current thread classcloader to load resources in the classpath
                SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(type, classLoader));
        List<T> instances = createSpringFactoriesInstances(type, parameterTypes,
                classLoader, args, names);
        AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(instances);
        return instances;
    }

//SpringFactoriesLoader.java
public static List<String> loadFactoryNames(Class<?> factoryClass, @Nullable ClassLoader classLoader) {
        String factoryClassName = factoryClass.getName();
        // 3.1  first find the configuration file
        return loadSpringFactories(classLoader).getOrDefault(factoryClassName, Collections.emptyList());
    }

private static Map<String, List<String>> loadSpringFactories(@Nullable ClassLoader classLoader) {
        ...
        try {
            Enumeration<URL> urls = (classLoader != null ?
            //  public static final String FACTORIES_RESOURCE_LOCATION = "META-INF/spring.factories"; 
            //4. spring.factories file is defined here
                    classLoader.getResources(FACTORIES_RESOURCE_LOCATION) :
                    ClassLoader.getSystemResources(FACTORIES_RESOURCE_LOCATION));
            result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

all the entries in spring.factories are loaded by below method -

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfigurationImportSelector#loadFactoryNames

```
protected Collection<String> loadFactoryNames(Class<?> source) {
        return SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(source, getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
```

SpringFactoriesLoader belongs to the spring-core library see below screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Improve the startup performance by creating a static list of candidates at compilation time.Just scan a static 'spring.factories' file, avoiding scanning a large number of class files in jars. Similar to @indexed in springframework 5.0. --`META-INF/spring.components`.
2. Centralized configuration management, concise and compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Good Read: https://blog.pchudzik.com/201903/spring-factories/

> **TL;DR**
>
> `META-INF/spring.factories` file is a special file picked up by the
> spring framework in which you can define how spring context will be
> customized. Documentation and spring-boot’s `spring.factories`.
>
> **But Why?**
>
> In the old days (before the spring-boot project) one had to configure context
> by hand. You had to be aware of what’s required for your application.
> What parts of the spring you’ll need, what database type you’ll be
> using, and for each of those prepare some XML configuration (java
> configuration was introduced in spring 3.x). With spring-boot things
> have changed. The troublesome and laborious process of configuring
> projects has been replaced by conventions and classpath scanning.
> Implementing such a mechanism can be easy but only if you deliver your
> framework as one huge blob that must be included with the project.
> Luckily (I’ve seen blobs…) spring-boot developers decided that they’ll
> ship highly specialized modules and you’ll be free to include only
> what’s necessary for you. With `spring.factories` file they are able to
> achieve exactly that. Each module can provide it’s own configuration
> which later will be merged and will comprise on spring context.