# Can spring boot's @Autowired inject dependencies from a jar(included in classpath) which is using GUICE for DI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, guice

I have a base package which is using **guice** for DI. I am using this as a library in my other project where I am using Spring boot So can I autowire dependencies from that jar to my spring boot project.
Let's say the artifact of the base package is com.package.dependency and my spring boot project is `com.example.spring-boot`
I have tried

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.spring-boot","com.package.dependency"})
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to autowire dependencies from an external jar by using componentscan if there are classes annotated as autowire candidates (`@Bean`, `@Component`,..)

`@ComponentScan` would not find any candidates for autowiring unless there are any candidates which are qualified for autowiring is available in the external library.

Instead, you can define an `@Bean` annotation and return a new instance of the class you want to return in your @Configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyExternalBean myExternalBean() {
     return new MyExternalBean();
  }
}
```

and in the class you need to use it, write :

```
@Autowired
private MyExternalBean myExternalBean;
```

If you need autoconfiguration, refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html. Here, you make use of spring.factories and specify the classes available for autoconfiguration so that you need not specify `@ComponentScan` in every project you use that external jar (applicable when the jar is developed by you or your company for use in other projects and not for third-party jars).

Comment: Yes thanks I know that, but my base package is actually a library so there are a lot of dependencies I need to inject in my project, so I was thinking can't spring look for modules in the jar and try to do the injection itself or for each dependency I have to define a separate bean.

Comment: If you need Auto-configuration classes that can be bundled in external jars and still be picked-up by Spring Boot, you need to use spring.factories. Refer answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107610/why-use-spring-factories-for-spring-boot-auto-configuration-instead-of-annotatio/32110368

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough detail in the question to show a definitive answer, but have you seen Spring Guice (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice)? It is designed for that kind of integration. You would need to identify the Guice `Module(s)` in `com.package.dependency` and register them as Spring components.